# Identifying index position of duplicates in a list and fetching the elements at the identified index of another list in Java

Tags: java

I have two list say 'src' and 'dest'. src contain some duplicates. I need to identify the index of the duplicate elements. After identifying the index, I want to fetch elements from the same index position of the 'dest' list

Comment: Showing some code / giving and example would help to clarify your question.

Comment: this sounds more like a statement than a quest :)

Comment: How large are the lists?

Comment: @Dave: The "src" and "Dest" list contains around 65k String elements. I am adding the values of src and dest from an csv file. src list contains multiple duplicates as in one source corresponds to multiple destinations.hence the duplicacy in src. for eg my src list contains src-[DXB,BOM,LND,PAR,NYC,DXB,DXB,HKG,SYD] and dest contains dest -   [JPN,HYD,PAK,SHJ,BOS,LAV,MEL,DUB,DXB]..Now each src corresponds to each dest as in DXB to JPN, BOM to HYD, DXB to MEL..etc Hence i need to identify the indexes of all duplicates in src list so as to identify the corresponding element in th dest list

Comment: is it one CSV file you are getting these routes from? are you sure you reading the file into your code properly - i mean why are you getting 2 different lists and then plotting the routes again ? you can surely identify indices and map, but that sounds like the wrong way of solving the problem. I think you should have a class called Route and you should read your CSV into a List of Routes. Obviously, my opinion is based on my limited understanding of your problem, so please excuse me if I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: So for each source, you are trying to find all the destinations?  In most cases you'll have just one, but in some you might have more than one.  In the example above DXB has three destinations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the algo to do this:

```
1. Create a HashMap <Integer,List<Integer> >  hm = new   HashMap <Integer,List<Integer> >();
2. Iterate through the source list and fill this HashMap such that The key is the each  number that you see and value will be a list that contains the list of indexes
 int counter = 0;
 for(Integer number : src){
     If(hm.contains(number){
       List<Integer> l = hm.get(number);
       l.append(counter);
     }
     else{
       List<Integer> l = new List<Integer>();
       l.add(counter);
     }

 }
3. Using these that were stored in Hashmap  to (print / fetch) the elements of destination list.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class list{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    l1.add("one");
    l1.add("two");
    l1.add("three");
    l1.add("four");
    l1.add("five");
    l1.add("six");
    l1.add("seven");
    l1.add("eight");
    l1.add("nine");
    l1.add("ten");

    l2.add("one");
    l2.add("two");
    l2.add("three");
    l2.add("eight");
    l2.add("nine");
    l2.add("one");
    l2.add("two");
    l2.add("three");
    l2.add("eight");
    l2.add("nine");

    List<String> l3 = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < l2.size(); i++){
        if( l3.contains(l2.get(i)))
        System.out.println(l1.get(i));
        else
        l3.add(l2.get(i));

    }

    }
}
```

This should print out all the strings that are at an index where an item in l2 is repeated. i.e six->10

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. The code is not fully complete.  The idea is that you create a new array where the values are a new class that contains the values plus their original position. Then you sort src and use the sorted version to find duplicates.  When you find one you can then get the position it originally had.

```
class EntryWithIndex {
   private int index;
   private Object value;

   ... constructor, getter, setters ....
}

List<EntryWithIndex> srcWithIndexSaved = new ArrayList<EntryWithIndex>();
int i=0;
for( Object o : src ){
   srcWithIndexSaved.add(new EntryWithIndex(i++, o));
}

Collections.sort(srcWithIndexSaved, new Comparator() .... );

for( int i=0; i<srcWithIndexSaved; i++ ){
   if( i>0 ){
       Object current = srcWithIndexSaved.get(i);
       Object previous = srcWithIndexSaved.get(i-1);
       if( current.getValue().equals(previous.getValue()) ){
         ... use current.getIndex() to lookup it up in the dest list.
       }
   }
}
```